# Google Maps save drawed polyline coordinates

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps-api-3

I want to save coordinates which i drawed on google maps.

This my map address i can draw line and distance. 
[LINK](http://nn-gis.com/map/draw/index.htm)

Please give me a hint how can i save coordinates this line any textbox..?

Comment: Here is a ["map editor"](http://www.geocodezip.com/blitz-gmap-editor/test4.html) based on the Google Maps API v3 Drawing Tools, which allows you to export the data as JSON or KML.

Comment: thanks for reply. but i`m need get coordinates and save directly to  mysql..

Comment: possible duplicate of [google maps api v3 exporting kml file of current map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659963/google-maps-api-v3-exporting-kml-file-of-current-map)

Comment: super! Thanks.. i can implement it..  and how can i delete any line.. Suppose one of line drawed wrong.and i want delete peace of line.. how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You already have the markers in a variable, just loop over them like:

```
var tempPosition, string="";
for (var i = vmarkers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    tempPosition = vmarkers[i].getPosition();
    if(tempPosition) {
        string += "[" + tempPosition.lat() + "," + tempPosition.lng() + "]";
    }
}
```